# Algorithm that transform array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to implement an algorithm over an array that performs this :
`[a,b,c,d,e,f] -> [a, b-a, c-b,d-c,e-d,f-e]`

Could anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: To implement the algorithm, we need an explanation of what logic you are expecting ; by the way, SO is not a code writing service, you have to come here first with some code you have tried

Comment: The first element will remain same? And pls elaborate your question, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of details. What are the types of the variables? What have you tried? What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

Given your array, we can achieve the desired outcome with the below method.

**Time complexity:** O(n) - Iterate through each element of the input array with **.map()**

**Space Complexity:** O(n) - Build an array of equal size as the input.

```js
const func = (arr) => {
    let joinedArray = [];
    let last = "";
    arr.forEach(elem => {
      toPush = elem + last
      last = "-" + elem
      joinedArray.push(toPush);
    })
    return joinedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the type of each array element is a number, then this should work:

```
const original = [1, 2, 3];
const after = original.reduce(function(acc, current) {
  acc.newArray.push(acc.last !== undefined ? current - acc.last : current);
  acc.last = current;
  return acc;
}, {last: undefined, newArray: []}).newArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map()` and for every item, but the first, subtract the current from the previous:

```js
const arr = [1, 5, 8, 12, 21, 100]

const result = arr.map((n, i, a) => i > 0 ? 
  n - a[i - 1]
  :
  n
)
  
console.log(result)
```